# Input type date not showing value

Tags: html, forms, date, symfony

I've got a project in Symfony2 (v. 2.2.11) in which I've got a calendar (fullCalendar) and when a user clicks in a day I open a overlay with a form and my start and end date got the selected day as value (format yyyy-MM-dd). If I inspect the element there's a value with the correct date but is not showing in input box, only shows when I click a date (I'm using jquery date chooser) the value appears in the input box (the new one).

This is my FormType code for start and end date:

```
    ->add('startDate','date',array(
        'label'=>'ueb_crossfit_class.form.event.labels.startDate',
        'widget'   => 'single_text',
        'format' => "yyyy-MM-dd",
        'attr' => array('class' => "input-date datepicker")
    ))
    ->add('endDate','date',array(
        'required' => false,
        'label'=>'ueb_crossfit_class.form.event.labels.endDate',
        'widget'   => 'single_text',
        'format' => "yyyy-MM-dd",
        'attr' => array('class' => "input-date datepicker")
    ))
```

This is the generated input (for start date):

```
<input id="ueb_crossfiterz_bundle_classbundle_eventtype_startDate" class="input-date datepicker hasDatepicker" type="date" value="2013-12-27" required="required" name="ueb_crossfiterz_bundle_classbundle_eventtype[startDate]">
```

[image: How the input shows even it has a defined value]

I've already tested with Firefox and Chrome and both doesn't show the value but only Firefox show that red line in input (as appear in image).

[UPDATE]
As asked in comments here's my js code for initializing fullCalendar:

```
$(function () {
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#calendar-holder').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev, next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,'
            },
            lazyFetching:true,
            selectable: true,
            timeFormat: {
                                // for agendaWeek and agendaDay
                                agenda: 'HH:mm{ - HH:mm }', // 5:00 - 6:30

                                // for all other views
                                '': 'HH:mm{ - HH:mm }'            // 7p
            },
            eventSources: [
                            {
                                url: Routing.generate('ueb_class_getEvents'), 
                                                        type: 'POST',
                                error: function() {
                                   //alert('There was an error while fetching Google Calendar!');
                                }
                            }
            ],
            eventClick: function(event) {
                            clickEvent(event);
                            return false;
            },
            select: function(start, end, allDay){
                            selectEvent(start, end, allDay);
            }
     });
});
```

Comment: Does your value appear without fullcalendar ?

Comment: No, I've got a button that puts today date as default and same thing happens.

Comment: Can you post the js code where you init the fullcalendar ?

Comment: @Jahnux73 Edited my question with the code you asked.